# Screen size на разных устройствах разного формата

Tags: java, android

Добро времени суток! Необходимо получить высоту экрана без учета status bar(а). Есть код, который получает эти данные:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    SizeDisplay = new Point();
    display.getSize(SizeDisplay);
    Log.d(TAG,"Width " + String.valueOf(SizeDisplay.x));
    Log.d(TAG,"Height " + String.valueOf(SizeDisplay.y));
}
```

На планшете все нормально вот данные logcat для планшета:

```
08-29 21:41:51.309 30926-30926/com.kuldiegor.Sudoku D/kuldiegor: Width 1200
08-29 21:41:51.309 30926-30926/com.kuldiegor.Sudoku D/kuldiegor: Height 1848
08-29 21:42:20.882 30926-30926/com.kuldiegor.Sudoku D/kuldiegor: Width 1920
08-29 21:42:20.882 30926-30926/com.kuldiegor.Sudoku D/kuldiegor: Height 1128
```

а вот на смартфоне в landscape ничего не меняется, и у меня уезжает вся разметка.

Для смартфона:

```
08-29 21:45:56.531 28855-28855/com.kuldiegor.Sudoku D/kuldiegor: Width 480
08-29 21:45:56.532 28855-28855/com.kuldiegor.Sudoku D/kuldiegor: Height 854
08-29 21:46:05.328 28855-28855/com.kuldiegor.Sudoku D/kuldiegor: Width 854
08-29 21:46:05.328 28855-28855/com.kuldiegor.Sudoku D/kuldiegor: Height 480
```

Подскажите решение данного вопроса?

Comment: Что значит "нечего не меняется"? Width и Height поменялись значениями.

Comment: На планшете видно как width был 1200 (портретный режим) то есть это высота затем стало 1128. 1200-1128=72 то есть учитывается высота statusbar. А на смартфоне если его поворачивать такого не происходит

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035591/6500349), вроде пока работает. Получаю размеры с RelativeLayout. MainForm это id главного RelativeLayout.

Код:

```
form = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.MainForm);
        form.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "PostW "+String.valueOf(form.getWidth()));
                Log.d(TAG, "PostH "+String.valueOf(form.getHeight()));
            }
        });
```